# Mean of stochastic process involving Cauchy random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The exercise I am trying to solve, asks to calculate the mean function $μ(t)$ and the autocovariance $R(t, s) = Cov(X(t), X(s))$ of some stochastic processes. The last one, were I am stuck, is:

$X(t) = cos(At+θ)$, where $Α \sim Cauchy(0, 1)$ and $θ \sim U(0,1)$ and $Α$ independent of $θ$.

I don't know if this process should have a mean. The Cauchy distribution doesn't have a mean but this doesn't necessarily mean that the process shouldn't have either. When I simulated values from this process and calculated the mean it *appeared* to be $0$ (I got a number near $0$ in all the simulations).

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: The process will definitely have a mean because it is bounded between $-1$ and $1$.  To go about computing the mean, I would try using trigonometric identities to split up the sum inside the cosine.  It may also help to remember how the Cauchy distribution can be defined in terms of the x-intercept of a ray with a uniformly distributed angle.